# Как сделать форму регистрации на сайте?

Tags: php

Ребята, помогите сделать форму регистрации на сайте, простую, логин, пароль и е-майл в базу чтоб заносились. Знаю что нужно PHP, но не знаю как именно писать код и подключить к индексному документу (

Answer (score 2):

в html:

```
<form action="save.php" method="post">
  <label>Login:</label><input type="text" name="data[login]" />
  <label>Pass:</label><input type="password" name="data[pass]" />
  <label>E-mail:</label><input type="text" name="data[email]" />
  <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

в Save.php

```
<?php
   if (isset($_POST['data'])){
$data=$_POST['data'];
      $query="INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (".$data['name'].",".$data['pass'].",".$data['email'].")";
    $res=mysql_query($query,$db);
    if ($res){ print('Good!');} else { print('Insert error!');}

   }
?>
```

Здесь не написал как подключаться к БД, хешировать пароль и прочие приятности. Думаю разберешься.